# How can you dynamically create Azure tablequery in node based on number of attributes?

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-table-storage, azure-cosmosdb-tables

I have an input that may be 1 attribute or more.  with azure tablequery, a query is created like this:

```
var tableQuery = new TableQuery()
                 .where('Name == ?', 'Person1');
```

If I have more than one attribute to query, it looks like this:

```
var tableQuery = new TableQuery()
                 .where('Name == ?', 'Person1');
                 .and('Address == ?', '123 Street');
```

How can I dynamically create the query without knowing how many attributes there will be?  In dynamodb i simply create a query string dynamically, but I don't know how to do it here where you have to append and .and() to the end of the function...

Answer (score 0):

You build complex queries by chaining multiple calls to `and`, e.g.:

```
var tableQuery = new TableQuery()
    .where('Name == ?', 'Person1')
    .and('AddressStreet == ?', '123 Street')
    .and('AddressCity == ?', 'New York');
```

Note that you don't have to build the `TableQuery` in one statement either, you could split it across multiple statements, perhaps with a conditional, e.g.:

```
var tableQuery = new TableQuery()
    .where('Name == ?', 'Person1')
    .and('AddressStreet == ?', '123 Street');

if (city) {
    tableQuery = tableQuery.and('AddressCity == ?', city);
}
```